# How to customize Magento2 themes

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

Can I get some general hints on how to extend and modify the Blank theme for Magento2? I have created a theme module, I have added web/css/source/_theme.less and _extend.less, and I understand how to use . Past that, changing this theme seems completely unworkable!

For example, if I move the currency selector, it is no longer a dropdown selector but transforms into a huge list of currencies.

If I try to change the navbar color, no matter how many color variables I override, none of the submenu colors actually change.

I have no clue how to change the catalog Add to Cart button action to "customize" instead of "addtToCart". If I just insert the Customize button block into an extending layout xml, nothing appears.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand that it is a bit hard for a new Magento 2 developer/designer to understand and debug it, but there are many great resources available to understand Magento's concepts. Thanks to Magento's large community.

Below are some reference links which may help you understand Magento 2's theming concepts:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html (Create a new storefront theme)

If you start learning from above link and follow each lesson, you will start grasping the basics of theme customization in Magento 2.

Apart from above, below are the links which can help you understand Magento 2's theme structure and its customization basics:

- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend-theme-architecture/
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html

Please let me know if you have some other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already read the docs on magento.com and have seen the top Google results on the topic. Those specific issues I mention in the original post are not covered, and some of them seem like unintended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

May be below URL help to you

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html